# A non-continuous idempotent linear operator in a Banach space

Tags: operator-theory

Does there exist a non-continuous idempotent linear operator $P: X \to X$ where $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space? That is, $P^2 = P$, and there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of elements of X such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \|P x_n\| = \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y\subset X$ be a non-closed linear subspace of $X$. Let $\{x_i\}_{i\in I_Y}$ be a Hamel basis of $Y$ and $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$, with $I_Y\subset I$ an extension to a Hamel basis of $X$.

Define $$P(x_i)=\begin{cases}x_i&i\in I_Y\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Extend by linearity. This $P$ satisfies $P^2=P$ but it can't be continuous because $$(P^2-P)^{-1}(\{0\})=Y$$ would be closed.